# Code it being affected by a cout which is not need it code

Tags: c++, cout

The program simply have a function which checks if a number is a perfect number. A perfect is the one for which sum of all its factors(excluding number itself) is equal to number it self. Like `6(1 + 2 + 3 = 6)` also `28`

I am seeing a werid behavior. There is `cout << ""`. If we remove this line code will not work properly if we put this everything works fine. I can't understand this

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int IsPerfect(int);
int main(){
    
    int N, j;
    cout << "Enter a value for N: ";
    cin >> N;
    cout  << "Perfect numbers are ";
    for(j=1; j<=N; j++){
        cout << ""; //If you remove this line no output will be printed
        if(IsPerfect(j) == 1){
            cout  <<  j << endl;
        }
    }
}

int IsPerfect(int a){
    int sum=0;
    for(int i; i<a; i++){
        if(a%i == 0){
            sum=sum+i;
        }
    }
    if(sum == a){
        return 1;
    }   
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `cout << ""` doesn't matter. You have undefined behaviour anyway, because `i` from `for(int i; i<a; i++){` is used uninitialized. Turn on _all_ compiler warnings to spot such errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code has nothing to do with the `cout`. Look in the loop in `isPerfect` function. The variable `i` has undefined value as it is not initialized. Initialize it like this:

```cpp
for(int i = 1; i<a; i++){
```

Comment: Well, the fun thing about UB is that adding or removing output statements can change the behaviour of the program, which is what OP observed, but still good answer.

Comment: What ouput you are seeing? with `cout << ""`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen That's exactly what I am saying

Comment: @MaheerAli I'm not sure you understood Yksisarvinen's comment. Your program has undefined behaviour, because of the issue mentioned in abdullah's answer. Programs with undefined behaviour do weird things. Remove the undefined behaviour and the weirdness will go away.

Comment: @MaheerAli its an empty string, there will be no output of an empty string (char*). When you study more about memory and variable initialization, you will see that there are some data called garbage which gets allocated. The behaviour you saw was entirely independent of the cout. The phenominon is dependent of garbage value, if bby chance the variable is initialized to 0,1, or any good number; you get your desired output. I didn't see any output in 3 runs.

Comment: @abdullahQureshee Hmm so we can say that its a co incidence.

Comment: @PeteBecker Noted. I have corrected it. I meant undefined/garbage value.